# Validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails application I have a contact column in the course model and in my form I have this code

```
  <% [ 'by email', 'redirect to an url' ].each do |contact| %>
    <br><%= radio_button_tag 'contact', contact, @contact == contact %>
    <%= label_tag "contact_#{contact}", contact.humanize %>
    <%= f.text_field :contact %>
  <% end %>
```

What I want to do is to validate the format of the text_field based on the radio button checked so if the by email is checked the format must be an email else if the redirect to a url is checked the format must be an url

Comment: by validation do you mean client side or server side, or both? if it is client side I recommend jquery validate (http://jqueryvalidation.org)...    you can just use a bit custom javascript to achieve that. If server side maybe you can do a conditional validation? is email / url an attribute in your model or just an option in the front end?

Comment: by validation I mean the one used by rails validate: contact, format: {??}

Comment: It's fine to indicate what you want, but you also need to demonstrate what you've done in an attempt to get what you want. What's the real problem? Not sure how to write the regexp?

Comment: there is a nice railscast about conditional validations:http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations

Comment: they are just an option in the front end like you see in my code

Comment: @MarsAtomic Not the regexp but i don't know how to do a conditional for this each if email and url was two different column it will be easy i can do it just by using something like this if course.email? condition elsif course.url other condition end but here they are just option in the front end

Comment: @qubit thank you for this railscast but this not solve my question I'm just enable to write the condition i don't know how to write it? should i do this if course.contact.email? or what this is what I'm enable achieve

Comment: @avinodra, I see. I feel like it is a bit of an overkill if you try to pass the params from the view to the model...and I am not sure if there is an easy easy way of doing this. (maybe through instance variables?)  Or you can just validate the format as (url  or email) on the backend and only do the option validation on the frontend? is it too big of a security issue? Another option is to add an extra attribute to your model that indicates whether the user choose url or email, and you can do the conditional validation {if contact.email?}

Comment: @qubit I was thinking to add another column but I said maybe there is an easy solution for these case, however thank you for your help you was helpful

Comment: @avinodra,np. and let me know if you end up find the easy solution! :)

Comment: @qubit I will for sure add another column (one for email and one for url) it is the easiest solution for me, I can easily know which one is checked, thank you again